# Objective-c - Check timestamp of a URL (file)

Tags: objective-c, file, url, timestamp

Given I have a URL like http://www.example.com/example.json

And I would like to check the last modified timestamp of example.json. Is there a way to do this with Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `– allHeaderFields` of `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

Comment: I'm trying this: `NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iana.org/about/presentations/vegoda-amsterdam-ripeupd-20110504.pdf"] MIMEType:@"application/pdf" expectedContentLength:NSURLResponseUnknownLength textEncodingName:nil];
    
    NSDictionary *test = [urlResponse allHeaderFields];
    DLog(@"%@",test);
    [urlResponse release];` but I'm just getting (null) in my log?

Comment: You should use NSURLConnection to retrieve the URL and check response in its delegate method: -connection:didReceiveResponse:

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line is there isn't a guaranteed way.  There is a `Last-Modified` header that you can examine in your `NSHTTPURLResponse`, but per the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) it is optional.